# How to validate xml with Namepace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I have an xml file with Namespaces like below.

```
<iwxxm:METAR xmlns:iwxxm="http://icao.int/iwxxm/1.0RC2" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/2.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:metce="http://def.wmo.int/metce/2013" xmlns:sams="http://www.opengis.net/samplingSpatial/2.0" xmlns:sam="http://www.opengis.net/sampling/2.0" xmlns:saf="http://icao.int/saf/1.0RC2" gml:id="metar-WSSS-20130919T040000Z" status="NORMAL" automatedStation="false" xsi:schemaLocation="http://icao.int/iwxxm/1.0RC2 http://127.0.0.1:8080/fullmoon-required/icao/iwxxm/iwxxm.xsd http://def.wmo.int/metce/2013 http://localhost:8080/fullmoon-required/wmo/metce/metce.xsd">
<iwxxm:observation>
<om:OM_Observation gml:id="obs-WSSS-20130919T040000Z">
<om:type xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/observation-type/IWXXM/1.0/MeteorologicalAerodromeObservation" xlink:title="Aerodrome Observation"/>
```

.
.
.and so on...

I have schema also for this. But the schema contains details for only tag. (See below)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="response">
        <xsd:complexType >
            <xsd:sequence >
                <xsd:element ref="request_index"/>
                <xsd:element ref="data_source" />
                <xsd:element ref="request"/>
                <xsd:element ref="errors"/>
                <xsd:element ref="warnings"/>
                <xsd:element ref="time_taken_ms"/>
                <xsd:element ref="data"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" default="1.1"/>

       </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

.
.
.and so on...

The problem I am facing is when I am validating using third party software or java program I am getting error like iwxxm:observation is not defined in schema.

Please advice on this to validate.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am facing is when I am validating using third party software or java program I am getting error like iwxxm:observation is not defined in schema.

Right. Each schema can describe only one namespace. 
(That namespace is specified with `targetNamespace` attribute in `<xs:schema>`)

But you can define multiple XML schemas for different namespaces
and import them in the one describing the whole your XML.

Look also at this question:
[Validate xml with multiple xsd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591154/validate-xml-with-multiple-xsd-files/)